# Is it possible to inject and move data in a binary file using Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following:

```
with open("inject.bin", "ab") as binary_file:
    binary_file.write(bytes(str('A'), 'utf-8'))
    binary_file.write(bytes(str('C'), 'utf-8'))
```

How do I inject `bytes(str('B'), 'utf-8')` in between `A` and `B` so that I know that I can find it using `f.seek(1)`?

Comment: I deleted my answer. I believe this is what you are looking for; [Append to a file after nth byte in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838919/append-to-a-file-after-nth-byte-in-python).

Comment: You cannot insert anything that way. You can just either replace existing bytes in already written bytes or append new data at the end. If you want to insert then you need to rewrite the file.

Comment: Yup - that's the answer. I couldn't find it. Thanks!